# How do data/observations themselves contribute to our ability to make determinations of whether a hypothesis is true or false?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, experiment-design, causality

Let's say that I have a hypothesis, and I'm trying to determine whether the hypothesis is true or false. If I remember correctly, [in statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing), the standard philosophical view is that, technically, we cannot determine whether a hypothesis is true or false, but rather whether the evidence (data) fails to reject the hypothesis. But how does the data/observations themselves contribute to our ability to make such determinations? In particular, are all datum created equal, or do some contribute differently / have superior "explanatory power"? Thinking about this naively, it would seem to me that data/observations that are "independent" of each other, or have lower correlation to each other, would have more "explanatory power" / "signal" / "contribution" towards our analysis / determining whether the hypothesis is true or false? But, in my studies of statistical inference, I don't recall such a thing being discussed / treating datapoints/observations differently in this way. Is there something to this idea, or am I wrong? If there is something to this idea, what are some good sources (textbooks) that I can use to dive deeper into this?

---

### EDIT

I guess this idea could also be thought of as how "economical" the data is. So, for instance, I'd be able to perform a hypothesis test to some level of accuracy with less data if the data are independent, but reaching the same level of accuracy with highly correlated data would require much more data.

Comment: Imo, in a data science world of massive amounts of information, the data gathered for analysis is *itself* the hypothesis.

Comment: @MikeHunter Could you please expand on what you mean by that?

Comment: Hypothesis testing developed in a 20th c of small data. In a 21st c of massive data it's been relegated to a subset of what data science/machine learning methods rely on -- a significant, nontrivial subset but a subset nonetheless. That said, my comments are tangential to the focus of your query. Perhaps more to the point is Popper's notion of *falsifiability* which contends that it's not possible to confirm a hypothesis as *true* whereas it is possible to confirm that it's not true or falsifiable. Still not sure if I'm helping. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *big* topic, so I will provide highlights.

It is true that statistics can not *confirm* a theory.  However, we can say if data are consistent with some assumption about the world conditional on other assumptions.

As for the "*are all datum created equal*" question, the answer is "No". My answer will have a causal inference bend to it, and I hope that is appropriate. As an example, [There is a hierarchy of evidence](https://libguides.mssm.edu/ebm/hierarchy#:%7E:text=The%20hierarchy%20of%20evidence%20is,information%20in%20the%20evidence%20hierarchies) when ti comes to medical trials, and the placement on the hierarchy depends on the design.

Assuming they are run correctly, randomized experiments are very high on the hierarchy because the design of the study excludes confounding factors.  Observational analyses, despite the sophistication if the analyses or credibility of the assumptions, are ultimately lower on the hierarchy because they are forced to make assumptions about confounders.

Importantly, there is *nothing in the data that tells you how credible the data are*.  Data are simply numbers, and we imbue them with meaning due to the context in which they are generated and the context in which we plan to use them.

Comment: The reason that I added the `causality` tag is because I've (partially) read Pearl's *Causality*, so I knew that this was also a valid question in that context, but my question is in the context of both statistical inference and causal inference. Unfortunately, experimental design is the area that I'm *least* knowledgeable about. With that said, even if all we have are anecdotal/opinion data (the lowest level of the pyramid), from what I remember about the scientific method and statistics, can't these data be combined in such a way that increases their credibility, such as in meta-analyses?

Comment: Also, so do you think the relevant study material for this area would be experimental design texts? Even if all I have are data from the lowest level of the pyramid, do you think reading experimental design texts would be the best way to learn how to utilise this data in the best way possible? Put another way, is experimental design useful even if all you have is observational data? Does experimental design give any insights about how to best use observational data (if that's all you have)?